# Truncated entropy

Tags: entropy, information-theory

If we bound a continuous random variable's probability distribution from below with $a$ and above with $b$, would the differential entropy of this truncated portion of the pdf just be

$$h(X)_{trunc} = -\int_a^b f(x) \ln f(x) dx ?$$

What might be wrong with this formula, and why isn't truncated entropy ever used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have a continuous random variable $X$ with pdf $f$ and we truncate it to some interval $I := [a,b]$ with $P(X\in I) > 0$ (I'm assuming this is what you mean because if we just clip a pdf to some interval in the sense of looking at $f\mathbf 1_{I}$ then it won't in general remain a pdf). Then we can use the CDF $F$ of $X$ to get the new density, so if $x\in I$ we have the truncated CDF as
$$
F_T(x) = P(X \leq x \mid X \in I) = \frac{P(X\leq x \cap X\in I)}{P(X\in I)} \\
= \frac{P(a \leq X \leq x)}{P(a \leq X \leq b)} = \frac{F(x) - F(a)}{F(b) - F(a)}
$$
therefore the truncated density is
$$
f_T(x) = \frac{f(x)}{F(b) - F(a)}
$$
(I was casual about $\leq$ vs $<$ since $X$ is continuous). Outside of $I$ the density is zero. Taking $\Delta = F(b) - F(a)$, this means overall the entropy is
$$
h[f_T] = -\int_a^b f_T(a) \log f_T(x) \,\text dx \\
= - \frac{1}{\Delta}\int_a^b f(a) \left[\log f(x) - \log \Delta\right] \,\text dx \\
= -\frac 1\Delta \int_a^b f(x)\log f(x)\,\text dx + \log \Delta
$$
so it's not quite your formula.

Regarding its use, truncations of random variables come up a lot, both in contexts like censoring but also in probability theory (e.g. Durrett's proof of the weak law of large numbers of his *Probability: Theory and Examples*) so I'm sure people are doing this somewhere.

---

If you actually are looking at
$$
-\int_a^b f(x)\log f(x)\,\text dx
$$
you could note that this is
$$
-\text {E} \left[ \mathbf 1_{[a,b]} \log f(X) \right]
$$
so we can still view it in terms of truncations. If you have a random variable with possibly infinite entropy then perhaps looking at truncations like this is useful, maybe in an asymptotic way, but I haven't personally seen that.

Comment: is there a name for $\Delta$? and is there a textbook that gives the formula "that's not quite my formula"?

Comment: @develarist $\Delta = P(X\in I)$ so I'd just describe it that way. I don't know of an official term for it other than that. And I also don't know of an official reference for the formula I gave but I'm just computing the entropy of a truncated density which is a standard enough thing that probably a lot of textbooks would at least discuss that

Comment: how might truncated entropy be useful? is there a demand or applications for measuring the disorder/unpredictability in specific segments of a pdf, for example, in its tails?

Comment: @develarist i was just googling it and came across this which might be a good place to start or get some other references https://www.atlantis-press.com/journals/jsta/125941168/view. They do pretty much the exact same computation I did here

Comment: thanks, as for practical implementations of truncated entropy, since histogram discretization is the norm when estimating entropy, does truncated histogram estimation present issues not encountered in regular, full-pdf histogram estimation?